# Deploy smart contract on blockchain only using EVM API without using geth or tuffle or ganache?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have implemented my personal blockchain using node js for IoT uses case so I now want to deploy smart contract code into this blockchain without using geth or tuffle or ganache OR Remix or web3.js so my goal is to use `EVM API` just to compile and execute a smart contract. 
So, how?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... are you using some Ethereum fork, or something that has EVM capabilities? You mentioned having "implemented a personal blockchain" using Node. Unless you built support for some EVM interpreter it won't be able to run EVM bytecode. If you are connecting to something like Geth or Parity *from* Node, you can simply deploy the bytecode directly. Can you clarify?

Comment: If you don't run a node, then where is EVM come from?

Comment: Maybe OP is asking about how to create an EVM interpreter as OP is deploying to his own blockchain

Comment: i succeded to  compile and generate bytecode and ABI  also the opcodes but i want to see the result of   the smart contract code !  add to  that  how can i  change this byte code to an adress and haw execute the byte code when i  ask the adress.

Answer (score 0):

**You can look at Contract ABI Specification**

Follow [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html)

> The Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) is the standard way to
>   interact with contracts in the Ethereum ecosystem, both from outside
>   the blockchain and for contract-to-contract interaction. Data is
>   encoded according to its type, as described in this specification. The
>   encoding is not self describing and thus requires a schema in order to
>   decode.

Also,

To integrate with Ethereum, requires an Ethereum client node like `Geth, parity`, `quorum` etc with RPC / IPC enabled.

If you are just interested in retrieving existing data from contracts, or sending offline signed transactions from the Ethereum public chain, you can just use a public node like `Infura` without the need to install a local client like Parity or Geth.

For smart contract development you can also install `Test RPC` which will create a network in memory without truffle or ganache.

> testrpc is a Node.js based Ethereum client for testing and
>   development. It uses ethereumjs to simulate full client behavior and
>   make developing Ethereum applications much faster. It also includes
>   all popular RPC functions and features (like events) and can be run
>   deterministically to make development a breeze.

for more details on testrpc , follow [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc)

To install testrpc

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

**Note**

> Ganache CLI is the latest version of TestRPC: a fast and customizable
>   blockchain emulator. It allows you to make calls to the blockchain
>   without the overheads of running an actual Ethereum node.

To install ganache-cli

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

Steps:-

1. Create smart contract for iot application.
2. Compile the contract using solc solidity compiler for nodejs
3. From the compiled JS contract object get the interface object

   The bytecode string, which is the binary representation of the
   contract is basically a set of (kind of) assembly instructions
   for the Ethereum Virtual Machine to execute
4. Deploy the contract to the testrpc network

[here](https://medium.com/@doart3/ethereum-dapps-without-truffle-compile-deploy-use-it-e6daeefcf919) is the detailed solution without using truffle or ganache

**To deploy only using Bytecode**

See Also to deploy using only bytecode : [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30177/deploying-a-smart-contract-with-just-bytecode) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying) and the [Yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

Comment: thank  you  for your help  but the  goal is use just EVM js   because i'm  implemented different  blockchain  (my blockchain is for iot  not for crypto.

Comment: You need to compile the contract and deploy to network ..does not require any tools or framework....tools make it easy....you can create a smart contract for iot ...compile it and deploy to the network... for that but the network should be up and running

Comment: thank you  i understand   but i want to deploy  the contract   on  my  own blockchain not on the network

Comment: what did you mean by your own network. ethereum support private blockchain network. so you need to create you own network.then deploy you smart contract on it.

Comment: i'm   getting into deep  on etheurum  not using etheurum (so try do store  the smart contract by  me and not using the etheurum

Answer (score 0):

Compile your contract (result file is /build/contracts/YourContract.json) and then deploy without truffle:

```
// Dependencies
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require("fs");

// Load Parameter
let PROVIDER = ...
let FROM_ACCOUNT = ...
let FROM_PRIVATE_KEY = ...

// Create web3 instance
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(PROVIDER), null, {transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1});

// Deploy
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(FROM_ACCOUNT)
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
    .then(txCount => {

        // construct the transaction data
        const txData = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            from: FROM_ACCOUNT,
            data: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/YourContract.json', 'utf8')).bytecode,
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(7900000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('12', 'gwei')),
        };
        console.log('nonce             : ' + txData.nonce);
        console.log('gasPrice          : ' + txData.gasPrice);

        // contract creation
        web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txData, FROM_PRIVATE_KEY).then(signed => {
            console.log('sign transaction  : OK');

            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
                .on("error", error => {
                    console.log('send transaction  : ' + error);
                    throw "DEPLOY FAILED";
                })
                .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
                    console.log('send transaction  : OK');
                    let contractAddress = (receipt.contractAddress === null) ? 'n.a.' : receipt.contractAddress;
                    console.log("CONTRACT_ADDRESS  : " + contractAddress);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Dependencies web3 v1.2.1 and fs v0.0.2